# Using AsyncCallback in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have to call a method on .NET object which is defined as

> IAsyncResult BeginListMetrics(    ListMetricsRequest listMetricsRequest,
>       AsyncCallback callback,     Object state )

Is it possible to use a powershell function as a AsyncCallback delegate? How?

Answer (score 8):

Scriptblocks can be converted into most types of delegates by casting as follows.

```
$myCallback = [AsyncCallback]{
  param( $asyncResult)
  # callback code
  if ($asyncResult.isCompleted) {
    get-date
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Xpw's answer is correct and casting Scriptblocks into delegates is generally useful, for the specific case of `AsyncCallback`, more is usually required.

Oisin Grehan's [PowerShell 2.0 – Asynchronous Callbacks from .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222052659/http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/10/09/PowerShell20AsynchronousCallbacksFromNET) explains the problem and provides a solution. [A fully worked example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404214529/http://poshcode.org/1382) is available. While Oisin makes the problem clear, his solution will be hard to understand if you're not familiar with [Register-Objectevent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent).

For full details see Oisin's great write-up. Briefly, an `AsyncCallback` is called via the Thread Pool and so will not be able to run a ScriptBlock because the thread doesn't have a PowerShell RunSpace. The workaround is to embed a small C# class that takes the `AsyncCallback` and raises an event, while `Register-ObjectEvent` is used to setup an event handler in PowerShell.