# Exception calling "BeginSendMessage" with "3" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: powershell, sdk, lync

I am attempting to execute a script for single contact IM (via Microsoft Lync), and have successfully ran the script all the way down to the last line:

`$null = $m.BeginSendMessage($d, $null, $d)`

Note:

```
$d = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary [Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.InstantMessageContentType, String]"

$d.Add($PlainText, "This is a test.")
```

Below is the exception Psh is throwing upon execution of this syntax. It appears to fail at initiation of the $null variable.

```
Exception calling "BeginSendMessage" with "3" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At C:\ScriptsPS\IM_SingleContact.ps1:75 char:1
+ $null = $m.BeginSendMessage($d, $null, $d)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument has to be a callback method. [Using AsyncCallback in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281955/using-asynccallback-in-powershell) has a simple example:

```
$myCallback = [AsyncCallback]{
  param( $asyncResult)
  # callback code
  if ($asyncResult.isCompleted) {
    Write-Host "Message Sent"
  }
}
[void]$m.BeginSendMessage($d, $myCallback, $d)
```

Comment: Possibly, but isn't the purpose of a Callback just to simply display results with EndRead and to close? 

In this case, I am passing the BeginSendMessage method the Dictionary object ($d) that contains the instant message, a Null value, and the Dictionary object again.

The argument for "BeginSendMessage" is the syntax that actually pulls the text from the object into the method, which then does the sending. This is my understanding, perhaps I still don't understand. I do know C# though..
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly an explicit cast to `[AsyncCallback]$null` would work for a null callback?